# How to serialize with jackson ArrayList sublist with Default Typing NON_FINAL?

Tags: java, json, serialization, arraylist, jackson

I'm having a problem DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL. When I try to serialize a sublist I expect that it gets serialized as

```java
["java.util.ArrayList",[0,1]]
```

or as

```java
[0,1]
```

but instead it gets serialized as

```java
["java.util.ArrayList$SubList",[0,1]]
```

The problem with this is that the class java.util.ArrayList$SubList can't be instantiated, throwing an error when I try to read **No default constructor for [collection type; class java.util.ArrayList$SubList**

The following example code reproduces the error:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JacksonCassandraSerializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(0);
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        String serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(list.subList(0, 2));
        System.out.println(serialized);
        // in the next line an exception is thrown:
        list = mapper.readValue(serialized, new TypeReference<List<Integer>>() {});
    }
}
```

A simple solution is to wrap the list into a new list, but I'm trying to solve this in a more general way, using the configuration of the ObjectMapper.

**This is the output of the main method:**

```java
["java.util.ArrayList$SubList",[0,1]]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No default constructor for [collection type; class java.util.ArrayList$SubList, contains [simple type, class java.lang.Integer]]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createUsingDefault(StdValueInstantiator.java:211)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:206)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:25)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer._deserialize(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:105)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromArray(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:50)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserializeWithType(CollectionDeserializer.java:259)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:41)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3051)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2153)
```

Comment: May you post the error?

Comment: Why do you serialize the name of the class?

Comment: Hi @LuiggiMendoza I'm serializing the name of the class because I need to use polimorphism: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization

Comment: Ugh, using polymorphism where you should not... Anyway, I would just rewrap the list into a proper ArrayList and let it be...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza thanks but this is a simplified version of the problem. This is used in a bigger and complex system that requires polimorphic types. We're trying to avoid that a valid usage of sublist ends up crashing the system.

Comment: Again, you should not use polymorphism for serializing/deserializing elements, it's a hell. And now you're seeing why.

Comment: Hi @LuiggiMendoza I think polymorphism is a powerful resource in OO programming, not using it doesn't look like a solution. So the problem may be re formulated as:  how can we map from a generic model that uses polymorphism to another model without polymorphism and back? (note: my model without polymorphism is JSON but can you suggest me a solution?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94617/discussion-between-gfournier-and-luiggi-mendoza).